Density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ vs measure of $\mathbb{Q}=0$
I have not studied measure theory yet, so I apologise if this is a bad question. I have read that the measure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $0$, which means that if you pick any real number, the probability that it is rational is $0$.
Suppose that I have a white straight line representing $\mathbb{R}$ and that I want to color the rational numbers black. I am wondering what the resulting line would look like.
From the measure theory point of view, it seems to me that the line would look completely white. However, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, my intuition suggests that the line should be totally black! Can you please explain to me what is happening here?
P. S. For me the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is one of the craziest results of math, as their cardinalities are different.

It is about being dense. One takes the closure, and there may be a lot in the closure.

@DietrichBurde is your comment referred to my last consideration?

Yes, and also to the sentences before: "However, since Q is dense in R, my intuition suggests that the line should be totally black!. But also a white set can be dense in a black one.

If your coloring means you color each point, then completely white line. If coloring means draw a neighborhood of it, then completely black line.

@温泽海 I meant coloring each point. It is so counterintuitive that the line looks white since your are coloring infinitely many points

Infinitely many, but only countably many. This is the point. As you said, the cardinalities are a big difference.

This is a good example of where infinity breaks our metaphors. For example, does paint have a "thickness?" such that if any point is colored black, points within $\epsilon$ of it appear black? (This is certainly true of real paint.) If so, the line looks black.
If instead we imagine that the color of any region will be the probability that we see a black 'dot' in it when picking 100 random dots to look at, then it will appear white, since the probability of a dot being black is zero by the measure zero argument. We're not going to reconcile this by analogy, it's just a question of how we make up the rules for how painting infinitely-small things works.
I think to get your head around density it helps to think of concrete decimal expansions, even though they normally take a back seat in analysis. A real number has a decimal expansion and so it is a limit of rational numbers (the truncations of the expansion). From this perspective, the difference in cardinalities is the at-first surprising result and the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense is the natural one.
Then to explain "measure zero" to yourself, it's all about the countable additivity. You definitely want a function you call a "measure" to be countably additive, because you need to say that if you take an interval and then the next half-interval and the next quarter-interval and so on, you'll have painted two full intervals. You also definitely want points to have measure zero. From this perspective, the fact that we can make a measure theory where there are sets that don't  have measure zero is the at-first surprising result, and the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ has measure zero is the natural one.

Excellent answer! Your question about the thickness of paint made me think of Gabriel's Horn too
